# Bitly API: Rest API Call in Java - Connection Refused Error

Tags: java, rest, api, url, url-shortener

I have been trying to connect Bitly REST API using Java. I want to use shorten method from [Bitly API](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html). Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class PostRequestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
             BasicConfigurator.configure();
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten");

                StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"access_token\":<my_access_token>,\"longUrl\":\"https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/18.1/Custom_Function_Plug-ins.html\"}");
                input.setContentType("application/json");
                postRequest.setEntity(input);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

              } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

              }

    }
}
```

I have referenced this code from https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/. Please let me know your thoughts whether I am calling the bitly api correctly or not. 
I am getting following error:

```
 0 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager  - Get connection for route HttpRoute[{s}->https://api-ssl.bitly.com]
31 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator  - Connecting to api-ssl.bitly.com/XX.XXX.XXX.21:443
21059 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator  - Connect to api-ssl.bitly.com/XX.XXX.XXX.21:443 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
21059 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator  - Connecting to api-ssl.bitly.com/XX.XXX.XXX.20:443
42080 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Connection closed
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api-ssl.bitly.com refused
42080 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Connection shut down
42080 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager  - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter@7225790e
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.persistent.plugins.urlshortener.PostRequestClient.main(PostRequestClient.java:70)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 8 more
```

I would appreciate if you could give me some inputs to fix this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to hit the bitly URL from a browser? Maybe your firewall is blocking it. I ran your code and it did not give me a connection refused.

Comment: Yes, I am able to hit the URL from a browser. However, if I try pinging the bitly url (>ping api-ssl.bitly.com) in the command prompt then the request is timing out. How can I resolve this? I also tried adding the following lines of code with proxy server details. It gives the same error:
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", <proxy_server>);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");

Comment: If you're working in an org or school, check with your network admin. If you're at home try changing your DNS to google's free DNS (8.8.8.8) - it might be returning a stale IP.